# Cannot edit textField and textView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple class that designs the display of title and content and other controller class that displays the content after fetching it from coredata, every thing works fine but the fields are not editable,  where am i making the error,

- repeating the same para as the editor was asking to made more words *
  I have a simple class that designs the display of title and content and other controller class that displays the content after fetching it from coredata, every thing works fine but the fields are not editable,  where am i making the error,

Design Class

```
import UIKit

class UpdateNoteDesignView: UIView {
    
    let notesUpdateTitle = UITextField()
    let notesUpdateContent = UITextView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        let updateStack = UIStackView()
        updateStack.axis = .vertical
        updateStack.alignment = .top
        updateStack.distribution = .fill
        updateStack.spacing = 5
        
        notesUpdateTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        notesUpdateContent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        notesUpdateTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        notesUpdateContent.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 300).isActive = true

        notesUpdateTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        notesUpdateContent.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        notesUpdateTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30)
        notesUpdateContent.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30)
  
        
        notesUpdateContent.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        notesUpdateContent.layer.borderWidth = 2
        
        notesUpdateTitle.layer.borderWidth = 2
        notesUpdateTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        
        updateStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        updateStack.addArrangedSubview(notesUpdateTitle)
        updateStack.addArrangedSubview(notesUpdateContent)
        addSubview(updateStack)
      
            
        updateStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        updateStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Controller Class

```
import UIKit

class UpdateNotesController: UIViewController {
    
    let updateDesign = UpdateNoteDesignView()
    var note: Note?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(updateDesign)
       
        
        updateDesign.notesUpdateTitle.text = note?.title
        updateDesign.notesUpdateContent.text = note?.contents
    }
    
    
 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add frame for UpdateNoteDesignView or set constraint for it in your controller.

Comment: @Nexus - thanks , i tried but it starts giving error , i added - updateDesign.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true , also how will this help making fileds editable ? Error - Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Comment: @Nexus - i am getting the desired design i want, my concern is how can i edit the contents in fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the issue is that frame is not set for your view. Try to add background color to UpdateNoteDesignView. You will not able to see it.

Please add frame/constraint for UpdateNoteDesignView as shown here and make changes according to your requirement.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var updateDesign: UpdateNoteDesignView!
    
    //       var note: Note?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateDesign = UpdateNoteDesignView()//frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 260))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(updateDesign)
        
        updateDesign.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        updateDesign.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450).isActive = true
        updateDesign.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350).isActive = true
        updateDesign.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        updateDesign.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        updateDesign.notesUpdateTitle.text = "Stack overflow"
        updateDesign.notesUpdateContent.text = "Developer"
        
    }
}
```